# can't install wine on ubuntu 20.04 focal

Tags: apt, wine

I have ubuntu 20.04 focal:

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

I had wine 7.0 installed, but I had to install some libpcre2 packages that broke wine. I was trying to reinstall wine using the instructions here (https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) , but now I get this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 7.0.0.0~focal-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I try to install wine-stable, I get this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable : Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 7.0.0.0~focal-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable-i386:i386 : Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libgphoto2-6:i386 (>= 2.5.10) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libsane:i386 (>= 1.0.24) but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libodbc1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and it cascades down until I eventually get to the point where there is a huge list of conflicting dependencies that give all kinds of errors. I don't know how to revert to the state before when wine was working.

I have these lines in my sources.list:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep wine
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
```

EDIT:
I tried to uninstall the libpcre2 packages to see if that would let me reinstall wine, but I got this list of errors:

https://pastebin.com/qkFdLxwX

I'm not sure why it's saying packages aren't going "to be" installed, when I told it to remove them.

Also, I'm not sure if this matters, but I'm using KDE Plasma.

Comment: Have you followed the steps outlined here: https://www.gloriouseggroll.tv/how-to-get-out-of-wine-dependency-hell/. Installing wine dependencies for i386 *might* solve most of those errors. You can also use `sudo apt list --installed | grep wine` to list all packages with "wine" in the title, then remove each package with `apt remove` to remove the package (but leave behind some config info) or `apt purge` to totally rid the package, followed by `apt autoremove` which should (hopefully, I'm not an expect) wipe the slate clean and allow for a fresh install. use Ubuntu's GUI Software center.

Comment: When I run that I get this: $ sudo apt list --installed | grep wine

libkwineffects12/focal-updates,now 4:5.18.7-0ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]

I tried to remove libkwineffects12, but it said it was going to uninstall kde and a bunch of other important things so I cancelled removing it. There are no other wine-related packages installed.